# Meaningful Auto Rename of File using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, logic, file-rename

Coding Platform: ASP.NET 4.0 C#

Consider the following scenario.

I am uploading a file named "StackOverflow.doc" to the folder Documents using `asp:FileUpload`.
But the folder documents already have a file named "StackOverflow.doc".
In this situation I would like to rename my file as StackOverflow(1).doc.

I do know how to make file names unique using GUID or by assigning temporary names.
But what I need is a windows explorer like solution. Which is the best way to approach it?

P.S: The solution should be redundant. That is, if there are files named StackOverflow.doc and StackOverflow(1).doc, my renamed file should be StackOverflow(2).doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach to getting a file name as you are asking (the file path logic not included for brevity):

```
string fileName = downloadFileName;
string fileExt = downloadFileExtention;

string fullFileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", fileName, fileExt);

int counter = 0;
while(File.Exists(fullFileName))
{
    counter++;
    fullFileName = string.Format("{0}({1}).{2}", fileName, counter, fileExt);
}

// Write the file to fullFileName
```

Comment: +1: a lot simpler than my logic. by the way, which is more optimised? Checking if File Exists on while loop till a match or taking the list of all files in a folder to a List<string> and applying your same logic on that list?

Comment: @yetanothercoder - I was considering to add a line about listing all files first as it will probably be faster (one hit of the disk instead of many). But if you do this in a multi-threaded environment you are risking overwriting a file that was written in the meanwhile by another thread (or risking an access violation exception).